# Groovy static compilation (@CompileStatic) turns types of class fields into `Object`

Tags: groovy, static-compilation

Compiling the following Groovy class

```
@CompileStatic
class StaticCompileTest {

   private def fieldInt = 3

}
```

results in this class, when decompiling the `.class` file:

```
public class StaticCompileTest implements GroovyObject {
    private Object fieldInt;
}
```

Changing the field to be `final` does not change the situation.

Why is the Groovy compiler in this case not able to derive the type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's inherently unsafe to assume that the type won't change.

see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_variables_vs_fields_in_type_inference

Comment: That is the perfect link to explain my question, esp. since it also handles the `final` case. Thank you.